# Unable to connect to Azure through SSMS (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms

Getting below error,everytime i try to connect to azure server through SSMS. Listed the IP client address in server firewall but still not working.

> Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53

I am using azure student license under Microsoft Imagine subscription, is that a problem?

P.S.:

- Tried to troubleshoot using this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine but still get the error message
- I'm using SQL Azure without Virtual Machine
- My connection string is

  > Server=tcp:test-dikna.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=test-diknaDb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=diknary;Password=;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
- This is my tracert result[image]

Comment: Could you give us just a bit more information? Like: Are you using SQL Azure, or a VM running SQL in Azure? Could you show us your connection string / the server you want to use (don't include passwords)?

Comment: @RickvandenBosch Ok done

Answer (score 1):

Windows azure SQL database has good troubleshooting guide and it is valid even today..

**References:**
[Windows Azure SQL Database Connectivity Troubleshooting Guide](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1719.windows-azure-sql-database-connectivity-troubleshooting-guide.aspx)

**one more interactive link :**
[Troubleshooting connectivity issues with Microsoft Azure SQL Database](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10085/troubleshooting-connectivity-issues-with-microsoft-azure-sql-database)

below are the steps(Pasted here to avoid link rot..)

**Verify Azure Firewall Settings and Service Availability:**
The error messages for this issue are self explanatory and you need to add your IP to allowable IP list ..and also check if your database is online in portal or there any outages

**Verify That You Can Reach the Server IP.**

1.Open a command prompt window and use the PING command to confirm that name resolution successfully translates your logical server name to an IP address. The “Request timed out” message shown below is expected because SQL Database will never respond to ping requests.

> C:>ping .database.windows.net
>
> Pinging data.sn1-1.database.windows.net [65.55.74.144] with 32 bytes of data:
>
> Request timed out.
>
> Request timed out.
>
> Request timed out.
>
> Request timed out.
>
> Ping statistics for 65.55.74.144:
>
> Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss)

If the server name resolves to an IP address, note the value and proceed with step 2.If this step fails, contact your network administrator or Internet service provider for assistance with fixing your name resolution problem.

2.From your command prompt window, try to telnet to port 1433 using the IP address returned in the prior step. This will test whether there are any firewalls/routers blocking traffic to port 1433.

> C:>telnet 65.55.74.144 1433
>
> Connecting To 65.55.74.144...

3.If Telnet is successful, the window will change to a completely blank screen. Exit and proceed to the next step.If it is not successful, capture the output and move to step 4.

From your command prompt window, repeat the test by trying to telnet to the DNS name instead of the IP address.

> C:>telnet .database.windows.net 1433

**Note:** If Telnet is not part of your default windows installation, you may enable it from Add/Remove Windows Components.

4.Use the tracert utility and capture the output showing the intermediate steps taken while trying to reach the server. This information will be useful if a network engineer is needed to troubleshoot the issue.

> C:>tracert 65.55.74.144
>
> Tracing route to 65.55.74.144 over a maximum of 30 hops
>
> 1 2 ms 1 ms 1 ms 192.168.0.1
>
> 2 6 ms 5 ms 5 ms 10.33.34.50
>
> 3 5 ms 4 ms 5 ms 4-1-753.DLLSTX-LCR-07.verizon-gni.net [130.81.107.26]
>
> 4 8 ms 5 ms 5 ms so-6-2-0-0.DFW01-BB-RTR1.verizon-gni.net [130.81.28.208]
>
> 5 44 ms 43 ms 44 ms so-11-0-0-0.LCC1-RES-BB-RTR1-RE1.verizon-gni.net [130.81.17.40]
>
> 6 49 ms 44 ms 44 ms so-6-0-0-0.ASH-PEER-RTR1-re1.verizon-gni.net [130.81.10.90]

if you face issues ,even when trying to reach the IP,, then you are not reaching the VIP and are instead being blocked between your client and the VIP.please refer to network section in first link for more steps on how to proceed further and you will need to involve network administrator at this stage

Comment: So i just capture my tracert result and show it to you?

Comment: This should be treated as guide and see ,if you are able to resolve the issue,if not post /update question along with what you have tried so far and waht is the issue you are facing after trying these steps